# exec 'echo' failing, how to check why?

Tags: php, debugging

I have a console PHP application that needs to write text to a file. If this size of the text is above 130999 bytes, then the data will not be written:

```
$line = '';
for ( $i=0 ; $i<130991 ; $i++ ) {
    $line .= 'i';
}

$size = mb_strlen($line, 'utf-8');
$line = "\n" . $size . " " . $line; // Adds another 8 bytes
$logLine = escapeshellarg($line);
echo shell_exec("echo {$logLine} >> data.log}");
```

Suspecting memory limit, I increased the PHP memory limit from 128 MB to 512 MB, with no change in the situation. **What might cause this limitation?**

**EDIT:**
Some more information:

```
$ xargs --show-limits
Your environment variables take up 3126 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2091978
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2088852
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

Comment: Did you remember to restart the web service after you changed php.ini?

Comment: There're like a dozen native ways to write files in PHP. Is this a proof of concept?

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, I did restart apache!

Comment: @Alvaro: The particular use case dictates that I use `exec` or `exec_shell` because in the end I am piping not to `echo` but rather to another application.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate issue. I am an experienced PHP developer and cannot resolve this issue.

Comment: i am with you. I voted you up again. Maybe it is not a php issue but a shell issue... isnt it possible to split the data in parts smaller than 130999

Comment: what operating system are you running on?  As Alvaro says in the answers below you are probably hitting a lenght issue.  try `xargs --show-limits`  if your OS has it.

Comment: @Doon: This is on Ubuntu Server 12.04. It looks like you may have found the issue: `Your environment variables take up 3147 bytes`. However, I am managing to get 100000 more bytes in there somehow, does that sound logical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP apart, what you are basically doing is creating and running a huge command in your system's command line processor.

I suspect that all command line shells have a maximum command size. That limit is 2047 on Windows 2000 and 8191 on Windows XP [[ref]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473). Linux will possibly have larger limits, but I don't think it'll be infinite. I'm pretty sure you've just hit your system's limit.

P.S. When PHP hits its memory limit, you get a proper error message.

Comment: Thank you Alvaro. Sure enough, `xargs --show-limits` has this to say: `Your environment variables take up 3147 bytes`. That is considerably less than the 130000 bytes that I am able to echo, so might the issue be elsewhere?

Comment: I'm not talking about environment variables, I'm talking about the command itself. `$logLine` is a PHP variable, not a shell variable. Your command contains a minimum of 130991 characters between `echo` and `>>`.

Comment: Of course! That is why I express surprise that the supposed limit is much lower than what is actually being used. Though on rereading the output o `xargs --show-limits` (edited into the question) I see that the size of the command buffer quite matches what I'm seeing. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but I still don't see how environment variables relate to this. You aren't using any env variables :-?

Comment: You are right, it is the size of the command buffer that I was hitting, not the env variables. I mistook that to mean the size of an argument sent to a CLI command.